# how to read bootstrap confirmation OK/Cancel event ?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am developing MVC application.
I am using bootstrp for CSS.

I am using alert/dialog for confirmation on the delete the record.
but was confused about how to read the response of user for OK or cancel.

```
 var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
            $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h6 id="dataConfirmLabel">Deactivation Confirmation</h6></div><div class="modal-body">Are you sure to deactive @Model.Name ? </div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button><a class="btn btn-primary" id="dataConfirmOK">OK</a></div></div>');
        } 
        $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
        $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
        $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
        return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [bootboxjs](http://bootboxjs.com) it uses Bootstrap by the way

I'll give you a sample code:

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
  if (result)
    {
      Example.show("You press Ok");
     }
   else
   {
      Example.show("You press Cancel");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i use click event on each modal button to perform the action i want.

I don't think that there is a result sent by the modal, as we can see in other languages.